# Tag wiki excerpts starting with "For questions about"

Tags: discussion, tags

A lot of the tags in the system use the "For questions about..." boilerplate to start the tag, is it worth getting rid of these and/or discouraging the format for new tags?

Comment: The format has been in use a while but I've done a lot of work with trying to make sure all tags have at least some form of wiki excerpt and this boilerplate is something I'm fond of so that's probably why you'll see it a lot.

Comment: What would the alternative be?

Comment: Whatever happens, we should make it clear to users that blurb tells you *how to use the tag*.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I've use the same format a lot myself, mostly because I've seen so many of the tags using this style. The alternative would be to just jump in with a description of the work in question. But that misses AncientSwordRage's point. It wouldn't tell the user anything about how to use the tag, it would just describe the work/author.

Comment: The point of wiki excerpts is to give a brief overview of what the tag is used for and how to, or how not to, use it in relation to other tags and asking questions. The tag wiki is really where information about the work/author should go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As 
[TheLethalCarrot](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/58193/thelethalcarrot) says:

> The point of wiki excerpts is to give a brief overview of what the tag is used for and how to, or how not to, use it in relation to other tags and asking questions. The tag wiki is really where information about the work/author should go.

So the part you are referencing that say "For questions about..." that's really there to say *use this tag* ("For questions about...").

If anything more tag excerpt should start that way or a similar way.